# Recommendation for hands-on Lie groups exercises

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, book-recommendation

I have an oral exam on Lie groups to prepare. During the semester we mostly had theoretical exercises to do, like proving such and such a theorem. However, the exercises during the exam are going to be more pratical, I guess like showing a group has some properties.

Through the semester, we've studied: compact groups, the Haar measure, the Lie groups and the Lie algebras, the exponential map, the adjoint representation, solvability, nilpotency, simplicity and semi-simplicity, and finally the Levi decomposition. So, I'm looking for exercises to drill these subjects.

Thank you!

Comment: What about the exercises to Humphreys book on Lie algebras? They are online with solutions.

Comment: Will have a look! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Problems And Solutions For Groups, Lie Groups, Lie Algebras With Applications, by Steeb, Tanski & Hardy.